# Area of a Triangle Inside a Circle?

Tags: geometry, circles, triangles, area

I have a circle of radius $r$ and a triangle inside that circle. Specifically, if you have the triangle $\triangle ABC$ inside a circle with only the one side $AB$ and an angle $\angle \text{B}$ opposite to the other side $AC$ known along with circle radius $r$, could you determine its area?
[image]

Comment: can you post a Picture please?

Comment: Can we make the following assumptions?  1.  $\triangle ABC$ is inscribed in the circle; that is, $A, B, C$ all lie on the circumference.  2.  We know the length $AB$ and the angle measure $m\angle ABC$.

Comment: Those data are not enough to find the area of the triangle. If you have a certain cord of the circle, then the opposite angle will be the same no matter where on the circle the third corner of the triangle is -- namely $\sin^{-1}\frac{|AB|}{2r}$

Comment: If those assumptions are valid, the area of the triangle can be determined.  What are you able to use, mathematically?  (The tools you have at your disposal determine what kind of solution can be presented.)

Comment: @HenningMakholm: The angle is opposite to "the other side", not the side of known length.

Comment: @Brian: Ah, I see. That seems to be a maximally confusing way of saying it rather than "one side and one of its adjacent angles known".

Comment: @HenningMakholm: There may be language issues, but yes, as you say, it is not possible to determine the area otherwise.

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/xspgzewtt/ here i posted the image. What is known is R, AB and angle ABC

Comment: @edwblackadder Which of the sides of the triangle is known to you?

Comment: @edwblackadder: Does my picture suits your question? :) The inputs are $\theta$, $a$, and $r$. right? :)

Comment: Yes, the picture is ok :)

Comment: @edwblackadder: You can notify persons in your comment by using @. :) Welcome to MSE.

Answer (score 3):

The angle at $C$ must be $\arcsin\frac{|AB|}{2r}$, namely half of the arc spanned by $AB$. This gives you all the angles in the triangle.

The law of sines then gives you the sides.

And then there are many ways to get the area, such as Heron's formula, or the sine of one angle times half the product of the adjacent sides.

Comment: Of course there are two possibilities for the angle (supplementary), nevertheless $\sin$ of the angle is known. The other angles can vary.

Comment: Is there a way to solve this without calculating the arcsin? Like if you were forbidden to use a calculator?

Comment: Do we know $|AB|$ at the beginning!? I think it should be computed from the inputs of the problem, i.e., $\theta$, $a$, $r$ as showed in the picture.

Comment: I found a way to solve it without using inverse trigonometric formulas. But I am pretty sure you won't be able to get away with out using normal trigonometric formulas.

Comment: @H.R. The question did say "one side ... known".

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Ooops, sorry, I was comparing with my added picture! :)

Comment: @H.R. $AB$ is known as well as $r$ and angle opposite to $AC$

Comment: @edwblackadder: OK, so I will change the pic a little! :)

Comment: @edwblackadder: Without _any_ trigonometric functions, I don't think so. You wouldn't be able to use the known angle for anything without _somehow_ putting an angle through a trig function at some point.

Comment: @dREaM thats fine, i was only saying that using a calculator would be forbidden and couldnt get $arcsine$ everything else is ok :)

Comment: @edwblackadder: Do you have trig tables available? :-P

Comment: @Henning Makholm sure why not, :) lets say i know them beforehand. Remember only calculator is not allowed. Its from a test of somekind :)

Comment: @dREaM could you share with me your way of solving this?

Comment: Ok, but it isn't pretty.

Answer (score 1):

Let $O$ be the center of the circle.

Let $\alpha=\angle ABO$ and $\beta=\angle OBC$

Then $\sin(\angle B)=\sin(\alpha)\cdot \cos(\beta)+\sin(\beta)\cdot \cos(\alpha)$.

Of course $\cos(\alpha)=\frac{|AB|}{2r}$ and $\sin(\alpha)=\sqrt{1-\cos^2(\alpha)}$.

Therefore if $x=\cos(\beta)$ we get

$\sin(\angle B)=\sqrt{1-(\frac{|AB|}{2r})^2}\cdot x + \frac{|AB|}{2r}\sqrt{1-x^2}$.

So we solve the equation for $x$ to get $\cos(\beta)$ (don't get scared, if you take the first summand to the left side and square it is just a quadratic polynomial in $x$).

And once we find $\cos(\beta)$ we have $|BC|=2r\cdot \cos(\beta)$

Finally, the area is just $\sin(\angle B)\cdot\frac{|BC||BA|}{2}$

Comment: could i have used the sine rule to get the $AC$ side? Then by the means of the cosin rule get the other side. Then calculating the area would be easy

Comment: you can surely use the sine rule to get $AC$. But getting side $|BC|$ using the cosine law is not possible.